# php file_get_contents на javascript

Tags: php, javascript, get, file-get-contents

Можете предложить альтернативу функции PHP `file_get_contents` на javascript?

Comment: Какие файлы вы с помощью javascript хотите получать?

Comment: Текстовые файли

Comment: точнее , из php файла

Comment: Со своего сервера? Тогда ajax запрос к скрипту на сервере, а на сервере php скрипт отсылает назад ответ в браузер. Страница не перезагружается. Полученные данные обрабатываете js.

Comment: пишу mobile app cordova html+ javascript не мой сервер

Comment: Здесь есть что хочу , но не работает )) http://javascript.ru/php/file_get_contents

Comment: У вас получается cross-domain ajax. Почитайте про CORS https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing и https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain Если на удаленном сервере стоит запрет на доступ с других доменов, то у вас проблема. Но возможно на том сервере есть открытый API для доступа к нему. Тогда нужно пользоваться им.

Comment: для этого есть cors proxy

Comment: аякс лучший вариант

Comment: cors proxy хорошо, но лучше добавить проксю прямо в свое приложение, не знаю, возможно ли это технически, по идее, если андроид, то это линукс, порты > 1024 можно и не под рутом открывать.

Comment: Нашел решение . Кому надо пожалуйста 

$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'http://example.com',
    function (response) {
        console.log("> ", response);
        alert(response);
});

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать эту функцию

```
function httpGet(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
httpGet("some url");
```

Если сайт не разрешает читать, можно использовать cors proxy (например https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.xhr = (url,callBack) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                callBack(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

xhr("http://site.domen/",(data) => {

});
```

Если запрос посылается на другой домен, к которому доступа нет (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`), создайте `php` файл с содержимым

```
$ch = curl_init($_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

И запрашивайте данные с помощью него

```
xhr("get.php?url="+url,(data) => {

});
```

Так же для удобства можно просто дополнить строку в функции `xhr` и обращаться к ней без префикса `get.php?url=` в первом аргументе (как в первом примере)

```
xhr.open("GET", "get.php?url="+url);
```